# контент шире экрана

Tags: css3, html5, google-search

Есть страница http://www.estetclinic.ru/uslugi/plasticheskaya/lica/chek-lifting/ 
https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly показывает, что страница оптимизирована, pagespeed тоже показывает качество 80% +. Но бот google search постоянно присылает,  что контент шире экрана. В списке присутствует указанная страница. Ручные проверки адаптивности, тоже не помогли выявить проблему. Можно было бы списать все на плохой инструмент, но на обслуживании есть и другие сайты, на которые search console bot не ругается.

Answer (score 0):

На указанном сайте заданы настройки viewport `maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no`, которые запрещают масштабирование на мобильных устройствах. Может из-за этого глючит что-то у робота.

Comment: у нас есть еще сайт https://litstile.ru/ там также используются эти настройки, но бот не ругается на него